# NHibernate disjunction resulting in AND queries instead of OR

Tags: nhibernate

This may be something obvious but I've been banging my head against it for a few hours and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

I'm trying to run a small piece of code to test adding OR criteria to an NHibernate query. This is the code I have:

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
    ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<TestObject>();

    int[] ids = {1, 2, 3};
    foreach (int id in ids)
    {
        ICriterion criterion = Restrictions.Eq("Id", id);
        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Disjunction().Add(criterion));
    }

    IList<TestObject> items = criteria.List<TestObject>();
    return items;
}
```

It's just something simple that I would expect to return all test objects with IDs 1-3. But, when I'm running the code, the query generated is to find an object with ID = 1 AND ID = 2 AND ID = 3. Which, unsurprisingly, doesn't return anything.

The mapping's set up correctly (I can add/edit/remove/list all of the objects) and there are objects in there with these IDs.

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Any samples of using Disjunction I've seen online all seem to use it this way. I just don't get why it keeps on using AND.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that you're creating a **new** disjunction every time (in a loop). What you need to do is:

```
int[] ids = {1, 2, 3};
ICriterion disjunction = Restrictions.Disjunction();
foreach (int id in ids)
{
    ICriterion criterion = Restrictions.Eq("Id", id)
    disjunction.Add(criterion);
}
criteria.Add(disjunction);
```

The syntax may be a bit wrong - I'm a Hibernate guy rather than .NET :-)

To clarify, your original code would generate something like (in pseudo-code):

```
WHERE (OR(ID=1)) AND (OR(ID=2)) AND (OR(ID=3))
```

Since there's nothing to "OR" to, disjunctions were silently omitted.

Comment: Magic, that worked a treat. Makes sense when I look at your code - I never thought that it would be "and-ing" together individual ORs.

The only minor change to your code is creating the disjunction as:
Junction disjunction = Restrictions.Disjunction();
(ICriterion doesn't have 'add').

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Updated code based on ChssPly76's answer:

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
    ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<TestObject>();
    Junction disjunction = Restrictions.Disjunction();

    int[] ids = {1, 2, 3};
    foreach (int id in ids)
    {
        ICriterion criterion = Restrictions.Eq("Id", id);
        disjunction.Add(criterion);
    }
    criteria.Add(disjunction);


    IList<TestObject> items = criteria.List<TestObject>();
    return items;
}
```